# Passing ArrayList<String[]> between activities

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-activity, bundle

I am trying to pass an `ArrayList<String[]>` between two activities, but can't seem to figure out how to do it.

I've tried `putParcelable` and cast the `ArrayList<String[]` to a `Parcelable` but that gave me the error `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable`.

I've also tried `putStringArrayList`, but that didn't work either.

Your input is appreciated!

**Main Activity**

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, NewChecklistActivity.class);
i.putExtra("checklists", checklistsArray);
```

**Secondary Activity**

```
checklistsArray = (ArrayList<String[]>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("checklists");
```

**StackTrace**

```
01-04 18:49:09.140: E/AndroidRuntime(2246): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-04 18:49:09.140: E/AndroidRuntime(2246): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.medusa.checkit/com.medusa.checkit.NewChecklistActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-04 18:49:09.140: E/AndroidRuntime(2246):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
01-04 18:49:09.140: E/AndroidRuntime(2246):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
01-04 18:49:09.140: E/AndroidRuntime(2246):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
01-04 18:49:09.140: E/AndroidRuntime(2246):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
01-04 18:49:09.140: E/AndroidRuntime(2246):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-04 18:49:09.140: E/AndroidRuntime(2246):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-04 18:49:09.140: E/AndroidRuntime(2246):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-04 18:49:09.140: E/AndroidRuntime(2246):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-04 18:49:09.140: E/AndroidRuntime(2246):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-04 18:49:09.140: E/AndroidRuntime(2246):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-04 18:49:09.140: E/AndroidRuntime(2246):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-04 18:49:09.140: E/AndroidRuntime(2246):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-04 18:49:09.140: E/AndroidRuntime(2246): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-04 18:49:09.140: E/AndroidRuntime(2246):     at com.medusa.checkit.NewChecklistActivity.onCreate(NewChecklistActivity.java:39)
01-04 18:49:09.140: E/AndroidRuntime(2246):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
01-04 18:49:09.140: E/AndroidRuntime(2246):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
01-04 18:49:09.140: E/AndroidRuntime(2246):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
01-04 18:49:09.140: E/AndroidRuntime(2246):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Can you define "didn't work either'?

Comment: Have you tried using just `putExtra ()` then `getSerializableExtra()` to retrieve?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel The methods I tried above didn't accept the format of `ArrayList<String[]>`.

Comment: @A--C Just tried that and it didn't accept it.

Comment: @TheNomad you need to cast. I checked the code by making a new project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Activity providing the data, use `Intent#putExtra()`:

```
ArrayList <String []> list = new ArrayList <String[]>();
list.add (new String [] {"a","b"});
Intent i = new Intent (this,YourTargetActivity.class);
i.putExtra("list", list);
startActivity(i);
```

Then to retrieve, use `Intent#getSerializableExtra()` and cast to `ArrayList <String[]>` :

```
ArrayList <String[]> list = (ArrayList<String[]>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("list");
```

You need to cast because the compiler cannot tell that the `Serializable` instance is really an `ArrayList<String[]>`. You will get an unchecked conversion warning, which makes sense because this does away with the type safety. It is fine though, because you know that you passed an `ArrayList<String[]>` so retrieving it won't cause any ClassCastExceptions.

One caveat however, is that all the elements must be non-null. For example, if `"a"` was instead `null`, when the Runtime recreates the List, a `NullPointerException` will be thrown.

Comment: I just added the code in my original post. I am getting a `NullPointerException`, not sure why. I also added `this.` in front of the `getIntent()` but that didn't help.

Comment: @TheNomad Where is the NPE? Make sure that `getIntent()` does not return `null`.

Comment: it definitely has to do with this code because I commented it out and everything works fine. I'll add my LogCat above.

Comment: @TheNomad It seems very likely that `getIntent()` is returning `null` for some reason. I stand by my code though, the cast should work under normal circumstances.

Comment: which makes no sense because I am passing in the `context`. I set it by `context = getApplicationContext();` in the `onCreate` method.

Comment: @TheNomad make sure that none of the elements in your arrays are `null`. Replacing `"a"` with `null` in my code *does* result in an NPE.

Comment: just checked and none of the values are null. this is really confusing. fyi, I am running the code in a `AsyncTask` background thread, but don't think that should be affecting it.

Comment: I suggest you do what I did and make a brand-new, as-simple-as-it-gets project to test this, then build functionality until you have a proof of concept for the final product.

Comment: ok, I left out `startActivity(i)` so I added that line in, and everything seems to work now, but... it automatically starts the new activity, which is not what I am looking for. I want it to send the `ArrayList` when I click that option in the menu.

Comment: @TheNomad Then `startActivity` only when the menu is clicked. I don't see the problem.

Comment: excellent, I just passed the `Intent` to the `startActivity` when the menu is clicked as you said. I was just afraid it would crash if the `AsyncTask` wasn't completed before trying to go to the next activity. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: You're welcome, but it's still a non-issue. You can check if an AsyncTask is in progress and simply not launch the Activity until it is done or disable the menu option until the AsyncTask completes. Also, for future questions, please make a [`SSCCE`](http://sscce.org/) so that you eliminate as many affecting variables as possible.

Answer (score 1):

try this where "i" is the Intent:

```
i.putStringArrayListExtra("nameYouWant", nameOfArray);
```

Comment: Actually I tried to put it in the bundle, but putting `i.putStringArrayListExtra` doesn't work either. Says `it's not applicable for the arguments`.

Comment: I wonder if there is a problem with your array list? What version of Java are you using?

Comment: @heLL0 i'm running Java 6 update 34 (1.6.0_34) so should be good

Comment: `putStringArrayListExtra` takes an `ArrayList<String>` as argument, not `ArrayList<String[]>`. I assume that's where the issue lies.

Comment: Exactly, none of the functions allows for `ArrayList<String[]>` only `ArrayList<String>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use create singleton Class to pass value

```
public class ShareData{
    private volatile static ShareData shareData;
    public static ShareData data(){
    if(shareData == null){
        synchronized (ShareData.class) {
            if (shareData == null) {
                shareData = new ShareData();
            }
        }
    }
    return shareData;
    }  

    public ArrayList<String[]> arrayList;  
}
```

set value in Activity 1

```
ShareData.data().arrayList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
ShareData.data().arrayList.add(strarray);
```

get value in Activity 2

```
public ArrayList<String[]> myArray = ShareData.data().arrayList;
```

Comment: This really should never be the go-to solution. Surely there must be a built-in way to do this?

Comment: This is a good way to pass value in any class. Can you example why this  really should never be the go-to solution? Thanks

Comment: Singletons are very test-unfriendly and this approach would require you to basically duplicate the signature of the data you're trying to send. Isn't this the exact reason why `putStringArrayListExtra` exists in the first place?

Comment: Actually, I have looked a bit deeper and couldn't quite find a suitable other option. Singletons are horrible for testing, but if you can't get around it then there are very few options. I'm interested to see if there are better solutions.